# Convert MS Access count and pivot query into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, count, pivot-table

I have grocery store database. I want to count how many products from each category are on a receipt.

Tables are:

- `Transactions` (id_transaction, quantity, id_receipt, id_product)
- `Receipts` (id_receipt, date, id_store, id_customer)
- `Products` (id_product, product_name, price, id_prod_cat)
- `Product_Categories` (id_prod_cat, category_name)

Desired output with sample data:

```
ID_RECEIPT |   desserts | meat |   juices | baker products| canned |
-------------------------------------------------------------------|
1          |   0        |   2  |    1     |     3         |   0    |
2          |   1        |   0  |    3     |     1         |   0    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried this query but with no success.

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Count(dbo.Transactions.quantity), 0) AS Product Count 
SELECT dbo.Receipts.id_receipt 
FROM dbo.Product_Categories 
INNER JOIN (dbo.Receipts 
   INNER JOIN (dbo.PRODUCTS 
      INNER JOIN dbo.TRANSACTIONS ON dbo.PRODUCTS.id_product = dbo.TRANSACTIONS.id_product) 
      ON dbo.RECEIPTS.id_receipt = dbo.TRANSACTIONS.id_receipt)  
   ON dbo.Product_Categories.id_prod_cut = dbo.Products.id_product 
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Receipts.id_receipt 
PIVOT 
    dbo.Product_Categories.category_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, this is the classic transpose query. Consider the following SQL which should be compliant in most RDMS's. For MS Access, you would use `IIF()` instead of `CASE WHEN` (and parentheses in the joins). The crosstab query with `Transform` is primarily an MS Access type while `Pivot()` is primarily an SQL Server function. However, below should work across database dialects.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Receipts.id_receipt,
    Count(CASE WHEN dbo.Product_Categories.category_name='desserts' 
               THEN dbo.Transactions.quantity END) As [desserts],
    Count(CASE WHEN dbo.Product_Categories.category_name='meat' 
               THEN dbo.Transactions.quantity END) As [meat],
    Count(CASE WHEN dbo.Product_Categories.category_name='juices' 
               THEN dbo.Transactions.quantity END) As [juices],
    Count(CASE WHEN dbo.Product_Categories.category_name='baker products' 
               THEN dbo.Transactions.quantity END) As [baker products],
    Count(CASE WHEN dbo.Product_Categories.category_name='canned' 
               THEN dbo.Transactions.quantity END) As [canned]

FROM dbo.Product_Categories
INNER JOIN dbo.Receipts 
INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUCTS 
INNER JOIN dbo.TRANSACTIONS ON dbo.PRODUCTS.id_product = dbo.TRANSACTIONS.id_product 
     ON dbo.RECEIPTS.id_receipt = dbo.TRANSACTIONS.id_receipt
     ON dbo.Product_Categories.id_prod_cut = dbo.Products.id_product 

GROUP BY dbo.Receipts.id_receipt ;
```

Comment: thank you sir, it works but more importanly I saw what I was doing wrong.